# Make column content width, not width: 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I put `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` for `ul` to achieve columns.

If `ul` splits elements into few columns, they have width of the widest `li` content in the column. But if there is only one column, it has 100% width.

What I want is to have this one column the size of its content.

```css
/* boilerplate */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}


/* actual code */

div {}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

li {}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>normal</li>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
    <li>short</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>normal</li>
    <li>just two</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>why</li>
    <li>full</li>
    <li>width?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRYjLd

Comment: sorry but I don't uderstand what you want

Comment: @CedricGourville the second `ul` is 100% wide and I want it to be just as wide as content inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display: flex` use `display: inline-flex`.

This switches the container from block-level (which takes the full width of its parent) to inline-level (which takes the width of its content).

This sizing behavior is similar to `display: block` vs. `display: inline-block`.

OR

Make the parent div a flex container with `justify-content: center`.

This confines the `ul` flex container to the width of the flex item, whose default is `flex-basis: auto` (content width).

```css
/* boilerplate */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}


/* actual code */

div {
  display: flex;             /* NEW */
  justify-content: center;   /* NEW */
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

li {}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>normal</li>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
    <li>short</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>normal</li>
    <li>just two</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>why</li>
    <li>full</li>
    <li>width?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange thing happened when I tried that: first `ul` was cut in half - one half outside the screen, second half on the left edge.

Comment: You're right. In your case, there's a better solution. Make the parent a flex container.

Comment: The second approach solved my problem. Thank you more then very much.

Comment: I just tested the codepen from question in Firefox vs Chrome and on Firefox it works right away, but in Chrome I have to apply your idea.